# Converting bone orientations from Y-axis to X-axis in Blender Python

Tags: scripting, armature, bones

I'm working on a project involving Armatures in Blender using Python scripting. The bones in Blender point down the Y-Axis but I'd like to point the bones down the X-Axis which Unreal favors. I've been working on a python script which takes an Armature and aligns all bones to the X-axis but I'm not getting the desired results.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to correctly transform the bone orientations from the Y-axis to the X-axis. Thank you!

**Edit:**
I've added the following more verbose description of my problem due to mod request.

This is my current Armature:

[image: Armature with bones on the Y axis]

The bones are oriented on the Y axis as Blender likes. However Unreal prefers them to point down the X axis which means all the bones have to be rotated on the Z axis by 90 degrees which looks like this:

[image: Armature with bones on the X axis]

The way I did this manually was rotating each bone on the Z axis by 90 degrees using the rotate command in edit mode. I used "Individual Origins" as the pivot point and applied these settings to the operator

[image]

I'm looking for a way to automate this into a single script since I have many skeletons to apply this to. It has to be done in EditMode so that child bones aren't rotated by the parents being changed, however EditMode python has no way to rotate bones XYZ euler and instead matrix math has to be used.

The goal of the script is to take each bone and rotate them on their individual origin on the Z axis by 90 degrees but I can't figure out how to do that part. Here's the closest I could get to having it work but it doesn't achieve the exact results.

```py
    import bpy
    from mathutils import Matrix
    from math import radians
    import math

    arma = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
    for bone in arma.data.edit_bones:
    rotation_angle = math.radians(90)  # Convert to radians

    # Calculate the rotation matrix for the desired rotation around Z-axis
    rotation_matrix = Matrix.Rotation(rotation_angle, 4, 'X')

    # Apply the rotation to the bone's matrix
    bone.matrix = bone.matrix @ rotation_matrix
```

This script was close however the results were not correct, the arms are both rotated to face the same way which is different than the results of manually running the operator:

[image: The Armature after running the script but the results are incorrect.]

At this point I reached the limit of my understanding of matrix math and I need some help if anyone can.

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.